# how to deal "failed to connect to Kubernetes master ip"

Tags: macos, curl, kubernetes, gcloud

I started learn Kubernetes, so I follow this guide https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/turnkey/gce/

I got an error after I run "cluster/kube-up.sh"

> Waiting up to 300 seconds for cluster initialization.
>
> This will continually check to see if the API for kubernetes is reachable.
>     This may time out if there was some uncaught error during start up.
>
> .........................................................................................................................................Cluster failed to initialize within 300 seconds.
>
> ### Last output from querying API server follows:
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  current
>                Dload     Upload  Total   Spent    Left speed
>     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to "[kubernetes-master (external IP)]"

So I tried to search about this error. And then found one solution. It said go to the "cluster/gce/config-default.sh"

```
 secret: $(dd if=/dev/urandom iflag=fullblock bs=32 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64 | tr -d '\r\n')
```

And then change 'dd' to 'gdd'. So I modified config-default.sh, But it doesn't work.

I don't know how to fix it. Is there are any solution about this error ?̊̈  Also in the /var/logs there are no logs about Kubernetes. Where logs are saved  ?̊̈

> My Mac version: mas OS Mojave
>                     version: 10.14.3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like GDD is [only available in MacOS](https://techblog.willshouse.com/2013/05/20/brew-install-gnu-stat/), about the Kubernetes logs you can have a look at [this other article](https://medium.com/devopslinks/viewing-logs-in-kubernetes-e055f936e187). If you would have a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster it would be easier to check the log by looking at Stackdriver.